# Make a mix of 2 Files Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey I am currently making a little tool just for fun. Its suposed to take a username and a password list and print out all combinations possible.

Python 2.7

My code

```
    while True:
    cnt = 1
    cntpw = 1
    currentusernameopen = open((usernamelist), "r")
    linesim = currentusernameopen.read().split("\n")
    usernameused = (linesim[cnt])
    while True:
        try:
            currentpassopen = open((passwordlist), "r")
            linesimpw = currentpassopen.read().split("\n")
            pwused = (linesimpw[cntpw])
            print usernameused+":"+pwused
            cntpw += 1
        except:
            cnt += 1
```

But when it reaches the end of passowrds it just prints:
USER1:
and stops

Comment: what type is pwused (type(pwdused))

Comment: String if thats what you mean

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't use exceptions to control "normal" flow of program
2. You should use meaningful names for your variables, and use underscores to separate words
3. You can just iterate on file, no need to read all and then split
4. And there is no need to keep counters like that

EDIT: my proposal for such exercise:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
users = open("users", "r")
passwords = open("passwords", "r")
for user in users:
    for password in passwords:
        print("%s: %s" % (user.strip(), password.strip()))
    passwords.seek(0)
```

strip removes all trailing whitespaces, here for last "\n"